# Use the same XIB for iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm building a simple app in Cocoa Touch that is to work on iPad and iPhone.

What are the techniques for creating XIB files that would work and look the same on these two devices? Can I use the same XIB for iPad and iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your app to "work and look the same on these two devices", just create an iPhone version and deploy only to the iPhone. The iPhone app will run on an iPad as is, and an iPad user will have the option to pixel-double it if the iPhone resolution is too small.

Comment: On more sophisticated or more complicated apps, it's almost always better to design separate interfaces for iPhone and iPad, as the two devices differ greatly in almost every aspect but the OS at heart.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using storyboarding if possible.  It does make support for multiple devices much easier than it used to be.  Is there a reason you don't want to use storyboarding or have you not looked at it yet?

Comment: Perhaps he needs iOS 4 support?

Comment: That's why I asked the question